# Nexus 5/10 only sometimes recognized by ADB

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm experiencing an issue with my Nexus 5 and Nexus 10 devices.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on VMware Workstation 9, and ADB only occasionally recognizes my devices. I find if I unplug and re-plug the devices, it'll eventually work, but it's annoying to have to go through this process everytime I disconnect my device.

Has anyone else experienced this/know of a workaround?

Comment: Damaged cable may cause that. Check with another cable

Comment: Oddly enough, the phone prompts me to allow USB debugging and the Windows host always recognizes it without an issue.

Comment: Then issue belongs to Ubuntu, i have no suggestion :(

Comment: Also your adb may be looped. Kill it manually in command line to force a reload

Comment: Tried that, to no avail unfortunately!

Comment: try running adb with root privileges and check if you run VMware as administrator in Windows

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a real answer, but it happens to me occasionally on various devices. I find that the best thing to do is to root the device and connect to adb over wifi. You can use an app such as "ADB Konnect" to enable wireless debugging.